# how to add c# dll to c++ project

Tags: c#, c++, dll, reference

I creating a notepad++ plugin and I want to add reference to c# dll

Is it possible to add C# dll to c++ project?

If so, how Can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COM Interop.
[MSDN Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736)

Comment: -1 NPP does not use COM, COM Interop is useless in this scenario.

Comment: The C# project sample that Peter posted is using interop services.

Comment: It's using interop marshalling and an IL rewriter to expose a DLL entry point. COM Interop only refers to interoperating with the native COM system, not all interop scenarios.

Interop can refer to 2 things in 2 directions, COM and platform code or DLL exports (pre-COM) and going from native to managed and the other way, from managed to native. This question refers DLL exports and going from native to managed.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [notepad++ plugin page](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html) which has a [c# project sample](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppPlugin.NET.v0.5.zip/download).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use the functions in that c# dll?
http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono

I don't know what libraries you will use but you may have to write a wrapper in C#.

Answer (score 1):

To stay a little bit more on the topic of the main question: you can but it's a bit complicated.

Take a look at this : http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ManagedCOM.aspx